# infinite scroll not working in framework 7

Tags: html, html-framework-7

kindly help me locate the eroor, ther preloader is working but the infinite scroll isn't working, it just displays the whole items instead of a limit of 10 items , then the other items should show when i scroll to the bottom of the page.

```js
var myApp = new Framework7();

var $$ = Dom7;

// Loading flag
var loading = false;

// Last loaded index
var lastIndex = $$('.list-block li').length;

// Max items to load
var maxItems = 60;

// Append items per load
var itemsPerLoad = 20;

// Attach 'infinite' event handler
$$('.infinite-scroll').on('infinite', function() {

  // Exit, if loading in progress
  if (loading) return;

  // Set loading flag
  loading = true;

  // Emulate 1s loading
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Reset loading flag
    loading = false;

    if (lastIndex >= maxItems) {
      // Nothing more to load, detach infinite scroll events to prevent unnecessary loadings
      myApp.detachInfiniteScroll($$('.infinite-scroll'));
      // Remove preloader
      $$('.infinite-scroll-preloader').remove();
      return;
    }

    // Generate new items HTML
    var html = '';
    for (var i = lastIndex + 1; i <= lastIndex + itemsPerLoad; i++) {
      html += '<li class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">Item ' + i + '</div></div></li>';
    }

    // Append new items
    $$('.list-block ul').append(html);

    // Update last loaded index
    lastIndex = $$('.list-block li').length;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="view another-view">
  <!-- Pages -->

  <div class="pages">
    <div class="page no-toolbar" data-page="blog">
      <div class="page-content infinite-scroll">
        <div class="list-block">
          <ul>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 4</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 5</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 6</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 7</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 8</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 9</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 10</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 11</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 12</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 13</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 14</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 15</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 16</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 17</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 18</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 19</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 20</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 21</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 22</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 23</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 24</div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 25</div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Preloader -->
        <div class="infinite-scroll-preloader">
          <div class="preloader"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have been able to the solve the problem

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: hello, sorry for just seeing your reply , what happened is framework 7 has inbuilt infinite scroll, one thing i discovered is you can't combine the two div classes named page and pages, if i remember correctly i removed one of it though i later didn't use the theme again because it didn't serve my purpose again